# Could not find capistrano-2.13.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I setup ruby on rails environment using http://jaysonrowe.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-ruby-and-rails-on-fedora.html. I installed mysql 5.5. Now when I clone a project from bitbucket and run bundle install, I get following error:

```
[xyz@xyz ruby_repo]$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Could not find capistrano-2.13.3 in any of the sources
```

When I execute rails -v in ruby_repo directory, I get following error:

```
[xyz@xyz ruby_repo]$  rails -v
Could not find abstract-1.0.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Below is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.10'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'rmagick'
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
gem 'mysql2','0.2.7'
gem "nokogiri"
gem 'activemerchant', :require => 'active_merchant'
gem "webrobots", "~> 0.0.10"
gem 'mixpanel'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'json'
gem 'vimeo'
gem "koala"
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "delayed_job"
gem 'mini_fb'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
gem 'grosser-ssl_requirement', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
#gem 'capistrano'
#gem 'capistrano-ext'
#To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'


# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

When I execute gem list, I get following output

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.1)
capistrano (2.13.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
highline (1.6.15)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.3)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.6.1)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.1)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.11)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.3.0)
```

However when I create a completely new project, I don't face any such issue. Can anyone please tel me what might be the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delete the contents of Gemfile.lock or the file itself.

Comment: I've had the same issue (Could not find capistrano-2.13.3 in any of the sources). It seems

Comment: ... this problem can easyly be solved this way. Gemfle.lock is a snapshot of gem depencies managed by Bundler. If you run 'bundle install' after deleting the file a new snapshot will be created without any outdated references. More information: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html.

Comment: what might be the issue ? this file is being used by others without any issue? Isn't there any other way?

Comment: It helped me to resolve the issue. But I am not sure if that is a right approach...

Comment: You should not delete your Gemfile.lock. If you only want a current version of capistrano you should run bundle update capistrano as suggested by Fa11enAngel. The purpose of the .lock file it to make it your decision when to update which gem. When you delete the entire file, you will get the latest version of every gem. That might lead to stuff breaking and is much more heavy handed than just updating capistrano. That being said, you should update all your gems regularly, but do that by running bundle update.

Comment: I concur with ajmumann.  You are essentially starting over with all the latest versions of every gem, and if its an application with a lot of code there is no guarantee stuff won't break.

Comment: You should never remove the Gemfile.lock file. Use `bundle update capistrano` instead, as Fa11enAngel said.

Answer (score 56):

This version is gone from rubygems.org. Update capistrano by running bundle update this way:

```
bundle update capistrano
```

This way you update only capistrano to the current version. If you delete die Gemfile.lock and run bundle, all you gem versions will be updated, what is often not what you want.

Comment: This is the safer route if you have a lot of gems that don't have their versions specified. If you delete the Gemfile.lock it'll install the newest versions of every gem that's not locked to a version in  the Gemfile. Running bundle update capistrano only updates capistrano.

Comment: Does anyone know why 2.13.4 was removed from rubygems?  Was there some really egregious security problem?

Comment: Check the commits on github: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commits/master

Comment: Thanks Fa11enAngel, I looked at all the commit messages between now and September and nothing stood out.  The act of removing a version from rubygems.org would not necessarily result in a git commit message.  Did you have a specific commit message in mind?  Do you remember what it was about, or could you provide a link?

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not checked the commits as I had no problem to update capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure the problem. The trouble maker is rvm.
I create a gemset for my app, and run bundle within this gemset.
However, for some reason, when I run rails c or bundle exec rails c, it still looks in the global gemset for the gems it needs.

So after I go to global gemset and install all the gems, it works. Not sure if it is rvm gemset trouble alone, or a combination of bundle + rvm gemset.